# C fgets and Arrays: Explanation

Tags: c

I have two questions regarding the following C code.

1. What is the purpose of `clear()` in the code? I thought
   it was so I could press enter to "stop" entering the 11 characters
   required for `myarray`, but it seems I could do that for the
   suceeding `scanf` calls as well.
2. Does `fgets` always close the buffer with "\n"? What if I put 11
   characters instead of ten? How would the function know to end the
   character with "\n"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void clear ()
{    
  while ( getchar() != '\n' );
}


int main() {


int value;
unsigned int second;
char myarray[11]; 

printf("Enter 10 characters:");
fgets(myarray, 11, stdin); 
clear();
printf("Enter an integer between -50,000 and 50,000:");
scanf("%d",&value);
printf("Enter an unsigned integer between 0 and 100,000:");
scanf("%ud",&second);

...
```

Comment: Mixing `fgets()` with `scanf()` is _often_ a sign of poor code.  Recommend to drop use of `scanf()` until you understand why it is bad to mix them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of clear() in the code?

The purpose of `clear()` is to remove all the remaining charaters in the `stdin` buffer, in case the inputed string is bigger than `11 - 1`.

> Does fgets always close the buffer with "\n"? What if I put `11` characters instead of ten?

It does not, if the input stream has the size of `11` characters or bigger, only `11 - 1` will be read, the `11th` character and those above are never read, leaving a space in `myarray[]` for the `'\0'` null terminator, they will remain in the buffer as will `'\n'`, hence the need for `clear()`.

**Example:**

If inputed string is `"qwertyuiopa"`, `q w e r t y u i o p \0` will be your char array, `a \n` will remain in the `stdin` buffer.

> How would the function know to end the character with "\n"?

`fgets` stops reading  as soon as the `11th - 1` character is read, as determined by its second parameter, regarldless of what character, or if `'\n'` is found, in witch case all the characters are read, including `'\n'`, and will be stored in `myarray[]`.

**Example:**

Inputed `"qwerty"`, char array will be `q w e r t y \n \0`, stdin buffer will be empty.

One last note, for total correctness, the `clear()` function should account for `EOF`:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: I don't understand the position: "_the remaining characters are not mandated to stay in the buffer by C standard_". `fgets` is a [byte IO function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p5), and as such it will [read characters from the stream as if by successive calls to the `fgetc` function.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p11) `fgetc` retrieves a character from the input stream and advances the stream position indicator. This would seem to leave characters in the input stream intact.

Comment: [Data read in from a binary stream shall compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p3); text streams allow some alteration, but this doesn't seem to justify "not mandated to stay in the buffer." Are you saying the the Standard allows characters in IO streams to spontaneously vanish?

Comment: Hmmm: suggest "_the 11th character is replaced by `'\0'`_" --> "_the 11th character is never read, leaving space in `myarray[]` for the `'\0'`_".

Comment: @exnihilo That means that I couldn't find anything in the standard the obliges fgets not to simply read all characters from the stream and, for instance, discard all the excess leaving the buffer empty, your links clarifiy it, I wasn't paying enough attention. Your suggestions are a clear improvement, I gladly accept them, ty.

Comment: This description of text streams is probably the most relevant for `fgets()`: [Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment.... Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line....](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p2)